# 2D Constrained Delaunay triangulation in CGAL using projection onto an arbitrary plane

Tags: 2d, projection, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

The question is whether CGAL supports 2D **Constrained** Delaunay triangulation of 3D points using a projection onto an arbitrary plane? I know that it is possible for basic 2D Delaunay triangulation without constraints via Triangulation_2_filtered_projection_traits_3 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443726/2d-delaunay-triangulation-in-cgal-using-an-arbitrary-plane/24444982#24444982). Is there anything like this for constrained case?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use this traits class too. However the class name has changed, it is now `Triangulation_2_projection_traits_3` in recent CGAL versions. I've update the linked page.

Comment: @sloriot, great, indeed, it works, thanks!

Comment: @sloriot Is there anything similar for operations over planar polygons in 3D? I found only the examples of usage of  CGAL::Projection_traits_yz_3<K>() [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/Polygon_2projected_polygon_8cpp-example.html), but nothing about projection in a specified direction.  Thanks!

Comment: You should use the class I mentioned, it will triangulate a 3D planar polygon. Doc is on its ways: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/5407